Train a neural network to predict the false positive rate of a segmentation model
I am trying to train a neural network to infer the false positive rate of an image segmentation model on the basis of the input image and the threshold.
To do so, I am considering a dataset organized in the following way
img1;th1;fpr11
img1;th2;fpr12
img1;th3;fpr13
--------------
img2;th1;fpr21
img2;th2;fpr22

I am trying to train a convolutional neural network composed of a feature extraction stage followed by a fully connected stage which gets the extracted features and the threshold parameter.
However, proceeding this way, I am not able to get good inference performance. Is there any well known approach to solve this kind of problem?

How large is your training dataset for this model? I think that's the usual limitation with this kind of approach: one uses most of the available data for the actual prediction / segmentation model. But an error prediction model can only be trained on hold-out data, which is often too small to fit a useful (complex) model. To get around this, you could try to not train a full supervised CNN but rather do something like unsupervised (or semi-supervised) dimensionality reduction (eg umap) for a pretrained model on the whole dataset and then fit just a small fpr prediction model on that.

In general, no, at least to my knowledge, this is not a standard thing to do. Most closely related are the many uncertainty quantification approaches that people have proposed over the years. You might be interested in conformal semantic segmentation, for example.

The whole data-set is composed of 20k images. I split the data-set in 10k images to train the segmentation model, 5k to train the FPR predictor, and the remaining 5k to test the FPR predictor.

Ah, interesting. That should be doable in principle, of course. A little experimental, but you could try enforcing monotonicity between the threshold parameter and the resulting fpr? Alternatively, maybe as a baseline approach: if your model is calibrated, you should be able to obtain a per-threshold FPR estimate simply from the pixel-level confidence, no? I think this would actually be the 'clean' approach: ensure that the model is truly well-calibrated, and derive your FPR estimates from that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
